What causes my Samsung phone to lag when I connect the charger?
I'm using a Samsung A03 and the factory usb-C to usb-C cable provided by Samsung. I've actually noticed this in other Samsung models I've owned in the past. If I'm playing a game when I connect the charger, it almost makes the phone completely unresponsive where it takes up to 15-20 seconds for any input to register. This usually leads to me hitting the home or active apps button multiple times thinking that maybe I missed the button the first time. The frustrating thing is that every input is queued leading to "System UI not responding" message and myself throwing a tantrum like a 3 year old

Which version of Samsung A03 do you have (there exists versions with 2GB 3GB and 4GB RAM). Have you enabled automatic updates via Wifi in Play Store? These updates will be applied when your phone is charging and as installing an app requires significant CPU resources this may affect your gaming experience. Also check the temperature of the phone. If it is getting too hot CPU will throttle thus reduce the speed.
